# How to fix these polygons properly without losing shape

Tags: modeling, objects

I have a problem. I am a rookie who wanted to merge two objects and I did it thinking that all of these polygons will join each other and live in a perfect harmony. Obviously they did not and now I'm stuck with a face looking like that. I tried looking for an answer but nothing really helps. Is there any way to somehow connect these in a way they will keep their shape? [image]

[image]

Comment: It depends on what this is and if it's important to have a clean topology. You could use a Boolean modifier but there won't be much harmony in the edge flow.

Comment: If only it was that easy.  You could try selecting them all, pressing  alt + m, and selecting merge by distance.  Then, just mess with the distance.  It probably won't work, but who knows.  P.S. it might be a good idea to duplicate the meshes before trying this, in case you are unable to undo it.